# Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15) at Function.Module._load

Tags: node.js, express, module, node-modules

I am getting following error

> Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25) at Module.require (module.js:596:17) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) at Object. (C:\Users\u8ser\Desktop\Todo\server.js:25:1) at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

PFB source code for your ref.

My server.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var database = require('./config/database');
  var morgan = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connected to DB");
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type : 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());

require('./models/routes')(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listining to port" + port);
```

My routes.js file

```
var Todo = require('./models/todo');

module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res){
    Todo.find(function(err, todos){
        if (err)
        res.send(err)

        res.send(todos)

      });
    });

 // create todo and send back all todos after creation

app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res){

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular

    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
           res.send(err);

       //get and return all the todos after you create another

       Todo.find(function(err, todos){
           if (err)
               res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
       });
    });

});

//delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res){
    Todo.remove({
       _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo){
        if (err)
        res.send(err);

        //get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos){
            if (err)
            res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});


// server.js 
// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

};
```

Kindly visit this [github link](https://github.com/roshantak44/todo) for full source code.

Comment: Pro tips for a better reception here: (1) put everything readers need in the question itself; (2) use the code formatting tools provided; (3) use succinct titles that describe your problem; (4) refrain from please-help-me pleading.

Comment: @Think-Twice: this is not my area, but would you be able to advise the Q author on supplying a larger sample of code, and putting the GH link at the end (or removing it entirely) so as to produce the required [mcve]? If that edit can be made the question can be reopened.

Comment: @Roshan Please have a look at my edit and approve. That is how you need to post your question for quick resolution and better support from community. Kindly follow others comments too in terms of posting questions. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in server.js file. Try with below updated solution

**Server.js:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var database = require('./config/database');
  var morgan = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var routes = require('./app/models/routes');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connected to DB");
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type : 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use('/api', routes); // you should add base path like this and assign routes

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listining to port" + port);
```

And in routes.js file remove /api because we added /api as base path in server.js

```
var Todo = require('./todo');

module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/todos', function(req, res){
    Todo.find(function(err, todos){
        if (err)
        res.send(err)

        res.send(todos)

      });
    });

 // create todo and send back all todos after creation

app.post('/todos', function(req, res){

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular

    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
           res.send(err);

       //get and return all the todos after you create another

       Todo.find(function(err, todos){
           if (err)
               res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
       });
    });

});

//delete a todo
app.delete('/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res){
    Todo.remove({
       _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo){
        if (err)
        res.send(err);

        //get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos){
            if (err)
            res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});

// server.js 
// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

};
```

The schema should be created below way but what you are doing is wrong

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogPost = new Schema({
  text : String,
  done : Boolean
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', BlogPost);
```

Comment: module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/routes'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\u8ser\Desktop\Todo\server.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: My bad. I imported routes.js incorrectly in server.js and that’s why you see above error, corrected that now. Updated my answer please check it will work now

Comment: module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/todo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\u8ser\Desktop\Todo\app\models\routes.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: That’s path issue. You need to change  var Todo = require('./models/todo'); to var Todo = require('./todo'); in routes.js file to fix the issue. I updated my answer please try once

Comment: one more issue please  help....I enter "things" and press the Add New button they just disappear.

Comment: Where is add new button? Where do you enter things? I don’t see such code in your question

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote my answer If my solution helped you to resolve your original issue

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer, but please help me on issue with this that nothing is appear on page when i add things in m todo app, I think its a server request problem i get an error of 404... please help me for this

Comment: Okey. What is the Api call that you are calling to add a todo? Please note we have added basepath I.e., /Api so when you are making a request it should be http://localhost:port/api/todos and the request method should be a post if you are trying from postman or from front end. Check on these things if you are not doing right then make changes as suggested otherwise share full error details and from where you are calling this Api and what are you passing to it. I will be able to help

Comment: please check the change code here https://github.com/roshantak44/todo  . I am soo stuck with this please help me and please make this todo app working

Comment: I can help you if you have any issues but it’s too much to ask to make your app work.

Comment: it gives me error GET /todos 404 44.373 ms - 144
POST /todos 404 394.171 ms - 145

Comment: you only help me in this

Answer (score 2):

I think you wrote bad path to routes.js file. 
Try

```
require('./app/models/routes')(app);
```

instead of

```
require('./models/routes')(app);
```